# Source integration for external site

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle, external-links

From time to time I link to an external site to analyze and process code samples I write on SO. [It does not happen too frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A772868+[failure-slice]+cti),but nevertheless. Currently, I encode the entire tiny program [into the URL](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/cti/cgi/cti?texta=sum%280,%20M,%20M%29.%0D%0Asum%28s%28N%29,%20M,%20s%28K%29%29%20%3a-%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sum%28N,M,K%29.%0D%0A%0D%0Aprod%280,M,0%29.%0D%0Aprod%28s%28N%29,%20M,%20P%29%20%3a-%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prod%28N,M,K%29,%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sum%28K,M,P%29.%0D%0A%0D%0Aprod2%280,_,0%29.%0D%0Aprod2%28s%28N%29,%20M,%20P%29%20%3a-%0D%0A%20%20%20sum%28M,%20K,%20P%29,%0D%0A%20%20%20prod2%28N,M,K%29.&nti=yes_plus) which obviously is prone to becoming out of sync.

So I am considering the following approach: After a code block (`<pre>`), a simple, generic link to the external site is added by the SO-user. When following the link, the external server fetches the referring page here on SO ; redirects to a specific link and then processes the code block prior to the external link. If there are several links on the page, the server can only reject analysis and some disambiguation by the writer of the link would be required like adding some `&uniqueref=`. While SO pages are
[not very conforming](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F27202175%2Fbetter-termination-for-sx-sum&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices) this all seems easily possible with some guessing.

Does this agree with the terms of use here on SO?

To me this approach looks less problematic than jsfiddle or ideone as the external site only provides a service but does not control the source code. So in the worst case the external site is defunct, but the entire code remains in the answer. On the other hand, it means that some robotlike pagefetches are noted on the SO-server.

Comment: Seems difficult to achieve, even simpler languages have huge libraries, and a snippet what could do without libraries ? ... but interesting nevertheless. I have a small IDE for SWI-Prolog, and I tough of making SO a privileged referrer. But licensing doesn't allows for this, I think

Comment: @CapelliC: Let's start with tiny steps!

Comment: I could give it a try. I'm in the process to redesign my small IDE with more Open WEB support...

Comment: @CapelliC: BTW, almost unrelated: It's "progaming" pro-gaming, OK?